# Decorating an overridden method and calling it and its super method

Tags: typescript

In a project I use decorators (TC39, not the experimental ones) to mark certain methods in a class for special handling.

```
/** A definition of the target function for a function decorator. */
export type DecoratorTargetFunction<This, Args extends unknown[], Return> = (this: This, ...args: Args) => Return;

/**
 * Decorator function for the After annotation.
 *
 * @param target The target method.
 * @param context The context of the decorator.
 *
 * @returns a method decorator.
 */
export function After<This, Args extends unknown[], Return>(
    target: DecoratorTargetFunction<This, Args, Return>,
    context: ClassMethodDecoratorContext<This, DecoratorTargetFunction<This, Args, Return>>,
): DecoratorTargetFunction<This, Args, Return> {

    const result = function (this: This, ...args: Args): Return {
        afterAll(() => {
            target.call(this, ...args);
        });

        return void 0 as Return;
    };
    Object.defineProperty(result, "isAfterAll", { value: true });

    return result;
}
```

I can then use them to mark certain methods like:

```
export class TestCoreBasics extends BaseTest {
    @After
    public shutDown(): void {
        ErrorManager.DEFAULT_ERROR_LISTENER.silent = false;
    }

}
```

The constructed decorator function is later called from a function which enumerates all methods in a class and its super classes and calls the one marked with the "isAfterAll" flag. This works very well, but now I need to handle inheritance.

I tried decorating both `shutDown()` methods (base and derived class), but due to enumeration either only the overridden or the base method is found and executed (depending on the order in the enumeration function).

Then I used the method enumeration where the derived method is used and added a `super` call there:

```
    @After
    public shutDown(): void {
        super.shutDown();
        ErrorManager.DEFAULT_ERROR_LISTENER.silent = false;
    }
```

Unfortunately, this calls the decorator method again, instead of the super method.

Note: I cannot change the enumeration to return both, the base and the overridden method and execute both, since there can only be one invocation of `afterAll` in a class (it's actually Jest tests).

How can I call the base method that was overridden?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I found involves manually walking the prototype chain:

```
/**
 * Decorator function for the After annotation.
 *
 * @param target The target method.
 * @param context The context of the decorator.
 *
 * @returns a method decorator.
 */
export function After<This, Args extends unknown[], Return>(
    target: DecoratorTargetFunction<This, Args, Return>,
    context: ClassMethodDecoratorContext<This, DecoratorTargetFunction<This, Args, Return>>,
): DecoratorTargetFunction<This, Args, Return> {

    const result = function (this: This, ...args: Args): Return {
        afterAll(() => {
            // Call the original method and all overridden methods in the prototype chain.
            const methods: Function[] = [];

            // Start with the current instance's prototype
            let proto = Object.getPrototypeOf(this) as { [key: string]: Function; };

            // Traverse up the prototype chain
            while (proto != null) {
                // If the current prototype has the method, call it
                if (typeof proto[target.name] === "function") {
                    const f = proto[target.name] as Function & { originalMethod: Function; };

                    // If there's no originalMethod property then this is the original method.
                    methods.unshift(f.originalMethod ?? f);
                }

                proto = Object.getPrototypeOf(proto);
            }

            methods.forEach((method) => {
                method.call(this, ...args);
            });
        });

        return void 0 as Return;
    };

    Object.defineProperty(result, "originalMethod", { value: target });
    Object.defineProperty(result, "isAfterAll", { value: true });

    return result;
}
```

It has to store the original methods for decorated methods (for the walk later) and needs to take care for both situations, a base method is decorated or it is not.